# How to convert a NameValueCollection to a Byte Array

Tags: c#

I have to pass parameters to a WebRequest. The parameters are available as a NameValueCollection. I have to return a byte array.

How do I do that?

Comment: However the WebRequest expects the bytes?  We need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean `HttpWebRequest`, since `WebRequest` is just an abstract class.  And, I'm assuming you're doing a `POST`, since with a `GET` you can just slap it onto the end of the URL.

So, you need to first create the body of the `POST`, which is written into the web requests's request stream:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var item in myCollection) {
  sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", item.Name, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Value.ToString()));
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); // remove the last '&'
```

At this point, you'll have a string buffer that contains a string like `"myVal1=Hello%20World&myVal2=5"`.  Now you want to write it to the request's stream:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://somewhere.url/asdf/asdf");
request.Method = "POST";
var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
request.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
stream.Close();
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
// ... process the response ...
```

Hope this helps.  I assumed your NameValueCollection was in the form of string -> object.  Adjust the "`item.Value`" part if it differs.  I also didn't URL Encode the key of a pair, since i don't think they accept url-encoded keys.

---

- [Sending Data with WebRequest - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)
- [POST with C#](http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you should serialize your NameValueCollection first.

```
 String str = "";

 str = mynvc.key + "=" + mynvc.value;
```

and then use this to convert this string to a byte array :

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding  encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
Byte[] myStr = encoding.GetBytes(str);
```

Comment: This is assuming only one value in the collection. If there are multiple values, what should be the way to separate them?

Comment: I wrote it like this way because i don't know how you keep your NVC items. Do they have a wrapper object or something? you can do it using foreach then.